# How to use Rest Template in Spring Boot Application to manage multiple endpoints?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

In my Spring Boot Application I want to manage in only one method multiple endpoints.
These endpoints are declared in my application.yml in this way:

```
spring:
    username: xxx
    password: acb132
    route:
      source:
        protocol: https://
        ip: 10.xxx.y.zz/
        root: "swdfr/"
        paths: >
            - "ofh/ert/hAFG5"
            - "ofh/ert/ryt54"
```

In my Service class I have created two different method with rest template to manage every endpoint individually, in this way

```
@ResponseBody
public void getWithRestTemplateGet1() {
    final String methodName = "getWithRestTemplateGet1()";
    try {
        startLog(methodName);

        String url = protocol + ip + root + paths.get(0);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate;
            if (url.startsWith("https")) {
                restTemplate = getRestTemplateForSelfSsl();
            } else {
                restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            }
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
            HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            logger.info("STATUS: " + statusCode);

        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        endLog(methodName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}

@ResponseBody
public void getWithRestTemplateGet2() {
    final String methodName = "getWithRestTemplateGet2()";
    try {
        startLog(methodName);

        String url = protocol + ip + root + paths.get(1);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth(username, password);
        HttpEntity request = new HttpEntity(headers);

        try {
            RestTemplate restTemplate;
            if (url.startsWith("https")) {
                restTemplate = getRestTemplateForSelfSsl();
            } else {
                restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
            }
            ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, request, String.class);
            HttpStatus statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
            logger.info("STATUS: " + statusCode);

        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage());
        }

        endLog(methodName);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

But I want to call the two endpoints in a single method with maybe a switch or a cascade of if.
Can you help me??
I apologize for my bad English and I hope I have explained myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with single method like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/template1", "/template2"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void getWithRestTemplateGet1() {
        //TODO
}
```

You can have multiple request mappings for a method. Just add @RequestMapping annotation with a list of values.

Comment: what is not clear? Use the RequestMapping annotation

Comment: Yes but how do I insert the endpoints from the application.yml ... and the method body always remains the same ??

Comment: And then I already use a RestController with a GetMapping which calls the method of the Service Class

Comment: Could you please explain to me how I connect / template1 and / template2 to the url's which are defined in my yaml file

Comment: sorry .. now I understand ... I had the solution in front of my eyes and I had not noticed